# Javascript HTA - Click Submit in Window

Tags: javascript, button, window, submit, hta

I have created a HTA with some Javascript code in it.

The user fills in the information in the HTA and clicks 'Submit'. This then opens a link and populates the page with the data input in the HTA. I then want to be able to automate clicking Submit at the bottom of the website.

I've got the below to open the link which is stored in a variable 'myLink'

```
window.open(myLink);
```

I'm just not sure where to go from there.

Some of the html of the web page is below

```
<form autocomplete="off" onreset="cc_f(this,event);" onsubmit="return isFormSubmitted(this, event);" method="post" action="" id="serviceForm" name="serviceForm">

<input value="" name="formAction" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="serviceId" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="startAfterStr" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="pricePerUnit" type="hidden">
<input value="" name="oldPersonId" id="oldPersonId" type="hidden">
<input name="timeStamp" type="hidden" value="">
<input value="111.7" id="documentWidthElement" type="hidden">

<div style="margin-top: 15px; display: none;" class="tsubfoot" id="cheader">

<span style="float:left;">

<input value="Back" onclick="var items=window.document.getElementById('bread_nav').getElementsByTagName('a');var item='/';if(items.length>0) item=items[items.length-1]; window.location.href=item;" class="secondary" type="button" style="visibility: visible;">

</span>

<span style="float: right; visibility: visible;" id="headerrightbuttons"> 

<input value="Reset" onclick="return myReset('/RequestCenter/myservices/navigate.do?query=orderform&amp;sid=477&amp;layout=&amp;');" class="secondary" type="button">
<input value="Add to a Bundle" onclick="return myAddRequisition();" class="secondary" name="submitorderform" type="submit">
<input value="Submit " onclick="return myOrderNow();" class="primary" name="submitorderform" type="submit">

</span>
```

This is not the only form on the web page - unfortunately it is poorly written and very long so unable to include it all. Just need to know how to reference the Submit button in the new window that has been opened.

Comment: "_... not the only form on __the web page__ ..._" => How is [hta] involved in the question then? Also, where you'd want to go, what is the actual question here?

Comment: I have edited above for a little more clarity. I have a HTA file. In the HTA file I have used some Javascript code. The code takes the information input in the HTA, opens a link in a new window and inputs the data from the HTA to the relevant fields. I need to automate the Submit function in the webpage. The rest of the code works.

Comment: Can you show the code populating the form on the web page? That would be a natural place to submit the form too.

Comment: The webpage is written in such a way that the data goes in to the url to tell it what goes where which makes it very straight forward. So the code just adds the data to the end of the url so it looks similar to below.
www.x.x.com/TicketCenter/mytickets/navigate.do?query=orderform&sid=477&Affected%20Item=Software%20Type=Request&Source=Phone&Subject=Test&Description=Test[PC: thispc, USER: 6TTW014, Area: Main Office] ---

Comment: Ok. Then you could "autosubmit" the form within a `window.onload` handler, like so: `document.forms['serviceForm'].submit();`.